# Ветвление проектов в GIT

Tags: git

есть проект интернет-магазин, для контроля версий используем git.

В процессе разработки пришли к тому, что нужно создать 2 версии немного отличающихся друг от друга.

Если грубо говорить, то разница в них лишь в функционалах вывода шапки, подвала и отображения корзины.

В процессе разработки могут быть следующие ситуации:

1. Дорабатываем функционал первой версии независимый от второй;
2. Дорабатываем функционал второй версии независимый от первой;
3. Дорабатываем общий функционал для обоих версий.

Думали о том, чтобы развести по двум отдельным проектам, но пункт №3, наиболее частая ситуация.

Если же работать в одном проекте, то в ветке master не получится иметь всегда актуальное состояние обоих проектов.

Может быть кому-то доводилось сталкиваться с подобной ситуацией и у кого-то есть решение или подскажите чего почитать?

Comment: master - текущая версия проекта, ветки (хоть по 1 для всех 3х версий, разницы особо нет) dev - для теста изменений, release - "бета тест"..

Comment: очень многим доводилось сталкиваться с такой ситуацией. Вопрос-то в чем?

Comment: так, возможно мы как-то не корректно git используем, давайте попробую объяснить. В master всегда актуальная версия проекта, оттестированая. Если внедряем новый функционал, создаем новую ветку, после тестов push-им её в master. Сейчас проблема в том, что у версий (об отличиях писал в исходном сообщении) отличается функционал и если, допустим мы дорабатываем то, что нужно в первой версии, то зачем это отображать в общем мастере, но при этом есть код, который необходим в обоих версиях

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Сделайте ветку `master1` и `master2` и пускай у вас там будут актуальные состояния проектов 1 и 2 соответственно. Изменения только для проекта 1 льете в `master1`.
Изменения только для проекта 2 льете в `master2`. Общие изменения делаете в отдельной ветке и потом мержите в оба проекта.
Возможность мержить, когда git за вас делает работу по удалениям, изменениям и всему такому очень ценна. Лучше её не терять.

Ещё один вариант, более правильный, но сложный в реализации.
Выделить общий функционал в отдельный репозиторий.
Создать разные репозитории под проекты. Общий функционал подключить к вновь созданным репозиториям в виде сабмодуля.

Comment: спасибо вам за ответ, звучит очень логично, пойдем тестировать

Comment: @para_bit Не, submodule — это создание проблемы на ровном месте, а вот три репозитория — идея может быть интересная. Проблема  этого решения в том, что исправления багов надо будет делать во всех ветках, а не только одной. На пустом месте создание дополнительной ненужной работы.

Answer (score 10):

Если разница между двумя вариантами небольшая, то рассмотрите вариант переключения между вариантами с помощью опции конфигурации самого приложения.

То есть не создавайте отдельные ветки для двух разных версий продукта. Вместо этого различающиеся моменты сделайте зависимыми от условия. Как конкретно это сделать зависит от технологий, которые используются.

Comment: да, тоже вариант, спасибо за ответ