# Ведение в гит параллельно двух версий проекта

Tags: git

Необходимо параллельно развивать и сопровождать две версии одного проекта. Часть изменений будет общая для обоих версий, а часть изменений будет специфична для одной из версий.

Как в таком случае организовать ведение проекта в гит?

Comment: Выносите общий код в отдельный проект / репозиторий.

Comment: Было уже https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1286600/218971

Answer (score 0):

Создайте отдельную ветку для второй версии, допустим ваша основная ветка это "main", сделаем ещё одну ветку "experimental":

`git switch -c experimental`

в ней вы можете cделать специфичные изменения. После этого вернутся в основную ветку

`git switch main`

и сделать общие для обоих веток изменения. Теперь нужно эти изменения добавить в нашу "experimental" ветку:

```
git switch experimental
git merge main
```

Если помимо "main" нужно больше изолированных версий, просто создайте ещё дополнительные ветки.

Comment: `git merge main` свалит все изменения, а не только общие. А раз в `experimental` еще и происходит расхождение, то еще придется конфликты разгребать.

Comment: @user7860670 
> Если помимо "main" нужно больше изолированных версий, просто создайте ещё дополнительные ветки.

Answer (score 0):

Две версии проекта, очевидно, ведутся в двух разных долгоживущих ветках.

Если версии отличаются довольно сильно, то общий изменения проще делать в одной ветке, и после этого переносить во вторую через rebase/cerry-pick, так как merge перенесёт не только последние изменения, в все, сделанные с последнего merge, среди которых когда-нибудь окажутся и специфичные для версии.

А вот если версии развиваются не параллельно, а только одна из двух, например, легаси, куда вносятся только исправления багов, и основная, где идёт развитие, то багфиксы можно делать в легаси, и спокойно мёржить в основную.